# setting tintColor with appearance proxy or self.view.tintColor?

Tags: ios

As per title.

What is the advantage in setting my `app tint color` with appearance proxy
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor`:

as opposed to just with

`self.view.tintColor`?

Or is appearance proxy just more powerful, being able to set tabbar item appearances etc.

Lastly, does this only apply to ios7? Or is the answer to my questions universal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As apple Docs says**: - Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is not supported in iOS 7.

**FYI**

"UIAppearance protocol with iOS 5 that has greatly reduced the work required to apply a consistent style to an application. Instead of having to customise the appearance of each UIKit control directly you can customise the appearance of a whole class of UIKit controls (e.g. all the UIButtons in an application). The UIAppearance protocol works by creating an appearance proxy for the UIKit class. Modifying the appearance of the appearance proxy modifies the appearance of all subsequent instances of that class".

To customize the appearance of all instances of a class, send the relevant appearance modification messages to the appearance proxy for the class. For example, to modify the bar tint color for all UINavigationBar instances:
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myColor];

**Note for iOS7**: On iOS7 the tintColor property has moved to UIView, and now has special inherited behavior described in UIView.h.
    This inherited behavior can conflict with the appearance proxy, and therefore tintColor is now disallowed with the appearance proxy.

Comment: From _Programming iOS 8_ page 655 by Matt Neuburg: "The headers and other documentation may appear to warn that `tintColor` is not a legal appearance proxy message. Don't worry; it _is_ legal. However, it is also true that the _normal_ `tintColor` property can conflict with appearance proxy settings. For example, setting an object's `tintColor` directly can undo a UIBarButtonItem's title font set previously through the appearance proxy's title text attributes."