# Identifying if class has selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to determine if there is a method on a class, however even the most simplest of tests is not working:

```
// Check for iOS 7 functionality
if ([[UITextField appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    NSLog(@"Supported");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not supported");
}
```

I'm executing this within **viewDidLoad**

Apologies if this is pretty basic - still getting to grips with objective c!

Comment: Check the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777487/setting-tintcolor-with-appearance-proxy-or-self-view-tintcolor the tintColor is now disallowed with the appearance proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I got this working - please advise if this is bad practice :)

```
if ([UITextField instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    NSLog(@"Supported");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not supported");
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks :) One other question, is there way to apply the tint color pre iOS 7? I only need it for the cursor on the text field.

Comment: If using this code and  you were on iOS 7 and above and you placed `[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` where `NSLog(@"Supported");` is then this would blow up. The reason being from iOS7 and above `tintColor` is disallowed on the appearance proxy. So really this isn't going to work correctly with iOS7, so no this isn't what you completely want you should probably be testing for the iOS version as well and if 7 or above don't use the appearance proxy.

Comment: Correct. Instead, you'd have to call `setTintColor:` on an instance of `UITextField`, not on the field's proxy.